# How to clear the header in list of contents

Tags: table-of-contents

I am a new Latex user, I would be grateful if you could help me to clear the header in the second page in my list of contents, I use `\thispagestyle{plain}` but unfortunately it isn't work to clear the header,
my code is:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{} 
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyhead[L]{Chapter \thechapter}
\fancyhead[R]{\leftmark}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}} 
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\begin{document}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Contents}
\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{plain}
\newpage

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listtablename}
\listoftables\thispagestyle{plain}
\newpage

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listfigurename}
\listoffigures
\thispagestyle{plain}
\newpage

\chapter{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\subsection{test}
\chapter{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\subsection{test}
\chapter{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\subsection{test}
\chapter{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\subsection{test}
\chapter{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\subsection{test}
\chapter{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\subsection{test}
\chapter{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\subsection{test}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this could help:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{} 
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyhead[L]{Chapter \thechapter}
\fancyhead[R]{\leftmark}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}} 
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\pagestyle{plain}
\begin{document}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Contents}
\tableofcontents

\newpage

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listtablename}

\newpage

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listfigurename}
\listoffigures

\newpage

\pagestyle{fancy}
\chapter{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\subsection{test}
\chapter{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\subsection{test}
\chapter{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\subsection{test}
\chapter{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\subsection{test}
\chapter{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\subsection{test}
\chapter{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\subsection{test}
\chapter{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\subsection{test}
\end{document}
```

\thispagestyle should set the style for the current page.
As can you see from the example I set a \pagestyle{plain} at the beginning of the file and then I changed it after the toc elements. This should fix your issue.

Comment: thanks but there is a problem when I use `\pagestyle{headings}` before the chapters, my format of heading style is change.

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't notice it. Use \pagestyle{fancy} instead of \pagestyle{headings}

Comment: working 100%, you are the best

Answer (score 0):

Just use this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyhead[L]{Chapter \thechapter}
\fancyhead[R]{\leftmark}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Contents}
\pagestyle{plain}
\tableofcontents
\newpage

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listtablename}
\listoftables
\newpage

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listfigurename}
\listoffigures

\clearpage

\pagestyle{fancy}

\chapter{test}
\section{test}
\lipsum
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\subsection{test}
\chapter{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\subsection{test}
\chapter{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\subsection{test}
\chapter{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\subsection{test}
\chapter{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\subsection{test}
\chapter{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\subsection{test}
\chapter{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\subsection{test}

\end{document}
```

[image]